How to Include the Build Recipe Alongside Source Code
I would like to include the Buildbot build recipe alongside the source code that the builder will compile.
Currently, we have all the project/branch recipes centralized in one location, which has become quite disorganized. I would prefer to have the build recipes located with the respective project/branch source code so that they can be managed independently from the generic Buildbot configuration.
Is this possible? I'm new to Buildbot, so any examples or documentation related to this would be greatly appreciated.
